# Can't connect to network printer while other's in the building can

Tags: ping, networking

I'm unable to connect to the shared printer in our business center. Every unit is on the same wired internet.

The instructions state that I should do Run->\10.10.41.11 but then Windows says it couldn't find that IP address.

I also can't ping the printer on my computer. I don't know anything about networking etc, but I noticed the Default Gateway on my pc is 172.16.xxx.xxx . Isn't that a problem to connect to 10.10.xx.xx then?

Anyway, the weird thing is that all other computers in the building can install the printer just fine... and they probably have the same Default Gateway as me.

I have a fresh Windows 10 installed, and no other software or hardware firewalls or anything like that.

What can I do?

Comment: sadly, Windows configuration is off-topic here.  You can try asking this question on [sf].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well default gateway should not be a problem as long as routing is done but I can say your company have weird network if hosts sits in 172.16 network when printer sits in 10.10. Usually company using just one addressing scheme so they choosing to use 172.16 or 10.X. First of all I would check if other colleagues also sits in the same network like you.
If yes then I would contact local administrator which should have more knowledge about infrastructure in your company because there could be forgotten ACL which blocking you access to this printer.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Well, the thing is that the building is a space where multiple small businesses rent an office unit. All utilities, including internet, is provided by the building owner. Probably not that safe for everyone to be on the same lan network, but it's a small building and we trust our fellow co-renters. The thing is that installing the printer works on all computers in the building, except on the computers in our small space, so the owner is kinda not that into figuring this out because it's only where we sit. We do have some switches and a NAS, but that's it...

Comment: Ok so that change things a little I thought only you cannot connect not all people on your space. So do you have your own router or other layer 3 device that act as a gate to the world or you connecting to building owner layer 3 device? By layer 3 device I mean router or layer 3 switch.

Comment: No, we don't have any of those. We have some switches to get some more lan ports, but even when I plug in my computer directly to the wall socket, it does not work. We also have a NAS that is attached to one of the switches, but as far as I know that only acts as a backup device, we didn't configure anything else. Also have a apache server running (xampp) on my pc for PHP development, but that's probably not relevant either...

Comment: so you need to talk with building owner since it is his device so you don't have even access to that to change anything or fix this problem

Comment: OK, thanks! Thought maybe some windows setting was bugging me here but apparently there's nothing I can do about it. I'll check with the owner.

Comment: no problem :) I hope you will figure it out with owner, if you found my replies helpful please press up arrow :)